# Factory class for spring-integration-redis components

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I'm using a redis list to perform like a queue in my integration app like this:

```
    @Override
protected IntegrationFlowDefinition<?> buildFlow() {
    return this.from(this.redisQueueInboundGateway())
               .handle(...);
}

@Bean
RedisQueueInboundGateway redisQueueInboundGateway() {
    RedisQueueInboundGateway redisQueueInboundGateway = new RedisQueueInboundGateway(Queues.QUEUE_NAME, this.connectionFactory);

    redisQueueInboundGateway.setSerializer(genericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer);

    return redisQueueInboundGateway;
}
```

There are any factory class like *AMQP* in Spring Integration Java DSL to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We add those factories for target protocols on demand.

Although, as you see, those Redis adapters are pretty straightforward in use and do that in your definition strongly correct.

Only one remark: that will work even if you remove `@Bean` from `redisQueueInboundGateway()` method and even make it `private`. Spring Integration Java DSL engine will take care about bean population and initialization for you.

Feel free to raise a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/issues) on the matter!

Comment: Issue created (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/issues/102). Thanks!